# Find all cities on GPS coordinates path

Tags: algorithm, geospatial, geo

What would be the best way to find all cities that are intersecting with a line determined by list of GPS coordinates? Do you have any better ideas than reverse geocoding points every constant distance (500m?)?

Comment: @m69 I'm sorry but I don't find this answer helpful in solving my question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 500m buffer around your linestring and then do a point in polygon search for points inside the buffer.

To speed things up make sure that you are using a spatial index on the points so that you only consider points with in the bounds of the buffer.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? I didn't fully understand your idea. Do you mean that I should store all nearby cities' boundaries and for every point that lies unto 500m from the path check in which city does it lie?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a spatial database of cities either as polygons or points, you can then make an intersects or contains query against it with your buffer polygon. Any spatial DB or GIS will support this natively